# Enumerable.Repeat with Union and Take does not return 'Take' values

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Very simple problem. I have a list of values which I want to pad out with empty values such that I always have X number of items returned.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30 };

IEnumerable<int> values = list
     .OrderByDescending( i => i )
     .Union( Enumerable.Repeat( 0 , 5 ) );

foreach (var item in values.Take(5))
   Console.Write( item + " ");
```

I would expect an output like "30 20 10 0 0 " But surprisingly I only get "30 20 10 0".

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Repeat( 0, 5 ).Take(3))
    Console.Write( i + " " );
```

This code will return "0 0 0 ". Likewise "`list.Take(3)`" returns "30 20 10 ".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that [`Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) removes duplicates. So you may want to use `Enumerable.Concat` instead which dsoesn't remove duplicates.

Another option i would prefer is to use [`Enumerable.ElementAtOrdefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx) to select the elements from an index created by [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) where the second argument is the desired count:

```
IEnumerable<int> values = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
            .Select(i => list.ElementAtOrDefault(i))
            .OrderByDescending(i => i);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of a SQL Union.

Comment: @IanQuigley a SQL `union` has an implicit distinct *too*. To avoid it, you need to use `UNION ALL` (which is then: concat)

Answer (score 5):

The notion of union, as a set-theory operation, has an implicit "distinct". If you don't want that: use `Concat` instead of `Union`.